# After finding a file, how to write parent directory name to new file?

Tags: bash, find

I'm working on a bash script which searches through subdirectories for each instance of a file and then concatenates the contents of each to a single file. When writing each file, I would first like to write the name of each parent directory before the content, i.e.,

```
Find: path/to/parentdir/file.txt
Write:
parentdir
<contents of file>
```

So far, I can find the files and get their contents but I am getting tripped up on extracting the directory name. Best attempt:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -exec echo "$(dirname {})" \; -exec cat {} \; >> bigfile.txt
```

But this just results in a lot of '.'s.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the first 2 lines of OP's sample output (`Find: ...` and `Write: ...`) are not actually part of what gets written to `bigfile.txt`
- OP has no requirement to preface the parent directory names with any special strings/patterns to make them standout from the rest of the text in `bigfile.txt`

If these assumptions are wrong we can come back and add some code to the answer.

---

**UPDATE**: Revisiting after realizing that `dirname` (as referenced by OP) is not providing the desired output (ie, `dirname` provides entire directory structure while OP just wants the name of the immediate parent directory).

One `awk` idea to parse the filename as well as `cat` the file:

```
awk '
BEGIN { n=split(ARGV[1],arr,"/")        # split name of input dir/file by "/"; put contents in array arr[]
        print arr[n-1]                  # print next-to-last element from arr[]
      }
1                                       # pass all input lines to stdout
' path/to/dir/filename
```

Pulling this into OP's `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -exec awk 'BEGIN {n=split(ARGV[1],arr,"/"); print arr[n-1]}1' {} \; >> bigfile.txt
```

---

Previous answer based on assumption `dirname` was providing what the OP wanted ...

There's no need to invoke a sub-process to call `dirname`, and also no need to `echo` said results; just call `dirname` directly, eg:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -exec dirname {} \; -exec cat {} \; >> bigfile.txt
```

[Adding @oguzismail's comment ...]

With GNU `find` you can use the `-printf` option to eliminate the `dirname` calls, eg:

```
find . -type f -name file.txt -printf '%h\n' -exec cat {} \; >> bigfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The '-printf' solution nearly has it but it is printing the whole directory structure; I just need the name of the parent directory alone.

Comment: ok, so `dirname` does not return what you want, right?  I've updated with another answer that I believe matches your sample output ...

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you so much! I will study your solution further and make sure to get more familiar with the awk command.